# Option to save file or not in database as blob ajax php

Tags: php, mysql, ajax, file, blob

I am successfully saving file in database as blob from ajax request to php file.
My ajax is like this

```
var file = $('#fileuploader')[0].files[0];
        var formData = new FormData();
        formData.append('file', file);
}
$.ajax({
            url: '../include/Addnewstudent.php',
            type: 'POST',
            dataType: "json",
            data: formData,
            processData: false, // tell jQuery not to process the data
            contentType: false, // tell jQuery not to set contentType
            success: function(data) {
                console.log(data);
               // window.location.reload(true);
            }, error: function(data) {
                alert("Error!"); // Optional
                //window.location.reload(true);
            }
        });
```

in my PHP i have

```
    $fileName = $_FILES['file']['name'];
    $fileType = $_FILES['file']['type'];
    $fileSize = $_FILES['file']['size'];
    $fileError = $_FILES['file']['error'];
```

where i check the file like

```
if ($fileError == UPLOAD_ERR_OK) {}
```

My question is very simple how can i make it in a way that when the i dont want to put file it is ok.Currently when i dont put anything in the `input(type file)` i always get error in the `$fileName = $_FILES['file']['name'];` saying `file` is undefined so i cant make an if condition as `if($fileSize = $_FILES['file']['size'] > 0)` or/and i cant leave the `input(type file)` empty because i will certainly get the `undefined index for file`. How can i be able to leave the `input(type file)` empty and dont get the error `undefined index : file`. Any idea is appreciated.

`GOAL`

The flexibility to save or not save file in database

Comment: are you sure that your if syntax is true ?

Comment: yes sir i can that the syntax is true since i am able to save the file for as long as the file is not empty. my goal is to be able to have the flexibility to not save file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on Keo's answer i played with it and i came up with this

`if (!empty($_FILES)) {`

and now i can save and not save based on my requirements. I achievement my goal to upload and not to upload depending on what i need

Comment: Just be aware that if you send more than one file, you will have to check ```if (!empty($_FILES) && isset($_FILES['file']))```

Comment: i see i will try to check on this i havent thought of trying it wil multiple upload thanks for idea then your answer will still be part of the big picture here

Answer (score 3):

You have to check if `$_FILES['file']` exist.

```
if (isset($_FILES['file'])) {
    // process file
}
```

Comment: instead of `if($fileSize = $_FILES['file']['size'] > 0)` i should use this one is this what you trying to say sir?

Comment: I added example, check it out @HogRider . Basically you cant ask about subarray if its 'parent' does not exists. Additionaly you can display structure of array with function like ```print_r($_FILES);``` so you can see whats there and whats not.

Comment: i had a problem with the code o thought it was running ok because it has no error when i checked the database even if i put a file i dont get to upload anything filesize 0 [BLOB - 0 B]. it did not upload anything setting `if(isset($_files['file']))` didnt work